# How to check what program started a service?

Tags: systemd, services

I scanned my own ports and surprisingly found that there is an `nginx`, and containing just an empty 'Welcome to nginx!' page, which further check. `systemctl` told me that it was started as the system boot. I am certain that I haven't configured it, and I want to find out that it was opened by what program (or who), and whether there are some security problems with my device.

While posting this I masked nginx. `systemctl --reverse list-dependencies nginx` returns only `nginx.service`.

Comment: What does `systemctl is-enabled nginx.service` return?

Comment: @Wieland it returns `masked` now

Comment: I have the same issue: I replaced `wpa_supplicant` with `iwd` as NetworkManager's Wi-Fi backend; both are started at boot, even if the former is disabled; who/what program started *wpa_supplicant*??